# Is $xyz=1$ needed in this inequality?

Tags: inequality

Is $xyz=1$ needed in this inequality?

Prove that if $xyz=1$ Then: $x^3y+y^3z+z^3x \ge xyz(x+y+z)$.($x,y,z \ge 0)$

I proved this using muirhead inequality with pairs:$(3,1,0)$ and $(2,1,1,)$.

which gives:

$x^3y+y^3z+z^3x \ge x^2yz+y^2zx+z^2xy=xyz(x+y+z)$

But I don't know why $xyz=1$ is needed?

Comment: It can be ignored.  The inequality is homogeneous...

Comment: are $$x,y,z$$ positive?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes sorry for that.

Comment: You can not use Muirhead here! Your inequality is cyclic and not symmetric.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg What do you mean by symmetric and cyclic?

Comment: If we'll replace $x\rightarrow x$, $y\rightarrow z$ and $z\rightarrow y$ we'll get another inequality. By the way, a cyclic permutation $(x,y,z)\rightarrow(y,z,x)$ does not change our inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it thins way: Divide by $xyz$ to get
$$
\frac{x^2}{z} + \frac{y^2}{x} + \frac{z^2}{y} \geq x+y+z = \frac{x^2}{x} + \frac{y^2}{y} + \frac{z^2}z\\
x^2 \cdot \frac1z + y^2\cdot \frac1x + z^2\cdot \frac1y \geq x^2 \cdot \frac1x + y^2\cdot \frac1y + z^2\cdot \frac1z
$$
which is clearly true by the rearrangement inequality.

Again, no need for $xyz = 1$ here.